# 「世界の何々」の表現の意味は何ですか。

Tags: meaning

名古屋{なごや｝に「世界{せかい｝の山{やま｝ちゃん」と言{い｝う手羽先{てばさき｝レストランがありますが、「世界の何々{なになに｝」の意味{いみ｝がわかりません。この表現{ひょうげん｝の意味合{いみあ｝いは何{なん｝ですか。

例{たと｝えば友達{ともだち｝とお話{はな｝し中{ちゅう｝に友達{ともだち｝を冗談{じょうだん｝で「世界{せかい｝の〜」で呼{よ｝んだら、失礼{しつれい｝ですか、それとも面白{おもしろ｝いですか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

普通は世界で有名な物、人に対して尊敬の念を込めて使います。例えば、「世界のトヨタ」とか「世界の黒澤」とか。でも、冗談で世界で有名でもないのに「世界の～」という事もあります。この「世界の山ちゃん」はそれでしょう。「世界のナベアツ」という日本だけで有名な芸人さんも冗談で使っています。友達を「世界の～」と呼んだら友達は嫌かもしれません。自分で言う分には冗談になるんですけど。

Comment: 説明してくれてありがとうございます！友達はいろんな国に旅行した事があるし、今アメリカで住んでいるし嫌いじゃないかもしれません。